# How to use firebase extension Chatbot with ChatGPT to connect firebase and secret manager?

Tags: firebase, google-secret-manager, firebase-extensions

The extension Chatbot with ChatGPT, is it safe to input my Openai key into this third party extension? While installing this extension, I see I still need to manually input Openai API Key instead of getting the apikey from my secret manager? So if I save my openai API key here in the Chatbot with ChatGPT extension, why or where I can use secret manager to save the sensitive key safely?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot for the info! I indeed find the key which I input in the Chatbot with ChatGPT in my secret manager! That is for me a step forward! Thank you again:)

Comment: I added the comment as an answer, so future visitors can see it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you paste the key into the field, when you hit "Create secret" then you'll be asked to save it to Google. As far as I know, the Chatbot with ChatGPT extension doesn't store the OpenAPI key. So you can add it to the Google Secret Manager without any worries.